# Galois representations with semisimple residue representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, galois-representations

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ be the ring of integers of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$, $G$ a profinite group (e.g. Galois group of local field or global field) and $\rho:G\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ a continuous homomorphism. If $\rho$ is semisimple as a representation of $G$, then it's not necessarily true that the reduction $\overline{\rho}:G\to \GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of $\rho$ is also semisimple. It leads to the following question:

> Let $\rho:G\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ be a continuous homomorphism, $\overline{\rho}$ its reduction and $\smash{\overline{\rho}}^\text{ss}$ the semisimplification of $\overline{\rho}$. Is there a continuous homomorphism $\rho':G\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ such that it has the same semisimplification as $\rho$ and its reduction is $\smash{\overline{\rho}}^\text{ss}$?

---

As pointed out in the comments, the answer to the above question is no. However, we may ask the following modified question:

> Let $\rho:G\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ be a continuous homomorphism, $m$ a positive integer and $\overline{\rho}_m:G\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p/p^m  \mathbb{Z}_p)$ its mod $p^m$ reduction, i.e., the composite of $\rho$ and the natural surjective morphism $\GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p/p^m  \mathbb{Z}_p)$. Is there a continuous homomorphism $\rho':G\to \GL_n(\mathcal{O}_L)$ where $\mathcal{O}_L$ is the ring of integers for some finite extension $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ such that
> -1 it has the same semisimplification as $\rho$;
> -2 its mod $\pi_L^m$ reduction is semisimple (as a $(\mathcal{O}_L/\pi_{L}^{m}\mathcal{O}_L)[G]$-module $M$ where $(\mathcal{O}_L/\pi_{L}^{m}\mathcal{O}_L)[G]$ is the group ring of $ G $ over $ \mathcal{O}_L/\pi_{L}^{m}\mathcal{O}_L $ and $M$ corresponds to $\bar{\rho'}_m$) where $\pi_L$ is a uniformizer of $\mathcal{O}_L$
> -3 the ramification of $L/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is less than $\phi(n)$ where $\phi(n)$ is some function of $n$?

Comment: No, such a $\rho'$ does not always exist. For a counterexample, consider a $\rho$ which is irreducible, but such that $\bar\rho$ is reducible and non-semisimple (this can happen).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks for your comment. In your example, I don't see why there isn't a representation $\rho'$ such that its semisimplification is $\rho$ and its reduction is $\overline{\rho}^{ss}$. Could you explain more details?

Comment: For a concrete example, let $G$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ consisting of matrices whose bottom left entry is $0 \bmod p$ (the Iwahori subgroup). Take $\rho$ to be the natural 2-dimensional representation of $G$. Then $\rho$ is irreducible, so the only representations with the same semisimplification as $\rho$ are conjugates of $\rho$. There are exactly two of these which land in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, namely $\rho$ and its conjugate by $[1, 0; 0, p]$, and both of them are non-semisimple mod $p$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler thanks for your counter example. But it looks like such a $\rho'$ does exists if $\overline{\rho}^{ss}$ is (absolutely) irreducible.

Comment: If you allow yourself to extend the coefficients, i.e, replace $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by the ring of integers in a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, then this is always possible.

Comment: @stupidboy Isn't the case of $\bar\rho$ irreducible pretty vacuous? In that case $\rho' = \rho$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler you're right, that's trivial case.

Comment: @naf Very nice!  Could you explain more details?

Comment: It might be instructive to think about the example given by @DavidLoeffler after adjoining $\sqrt{p}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. If you work this out then it should be easy to see what to do in general.

Comment: Note that all this theory has been very intensively studied because of applications in Iwasawa theory, beginning with Ribet's converse to Herbrand; the main tool is thinking about the action of $G$ on the Bruhat-Tits building of $GL_n / \mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: You can get a lot of intuition for what's going on just by looking at elliptic curves, using the dictionary between lattices in the $p$-adic Galois representation of $E$ and Tate modules of elliptic curves with a $p$-power isogeny to $E$. There, the analogue of your question is: if $E$ admits a cyclic $p$-isogeny, then is $E$ isogenous to some elliptic curve $E'$ that admits two independent $p$-isogenies? The answer is, of course, no, unless $E$ already has a cyclic $p^2$ isogeny.

Comment: Downvoting this -- the new "bounty question" is something that was suggested to you as an exercise, and @naf even give you a strong hint on how to do it. You are expected to put in a bit of work of your own here.

Comment: @David Loeffler Is there really an affirmative answer to the bounty question? I tried it, but I failed. My understanding is the following:  take $n=2,m=1$ and $\rho$ an absolutely irreducible representation of $G$ such that its mod $p$ reduction is reducible and non-semisimple. Then the only representations of $\rho$ with the same semisimplification as $\rho$ are conjugates of $\rho$. Recall the fact that if $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field, then a representation $G\to {\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{F})$  is semisimple if and only if its image has order prime to the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Since conjugation doesn't change the order of the image, all conjugation of $\rho$ should not have semisimple reduction. Maybe I misunderstood something, your any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Not all conjugations in $GL_2(L)$ are conjugations in $GL_2(\mathcal{O}_L)$.

Comment: @stupidboy [These lecture notes](http://people.brandeis.edu/~jbellaic/RibetHawaii3.pdf) might help. The point is that by extending from $\mathbb Q_p$ to a finite ramified extension, you add many new lattices in the Bruhat-Tits building in between all the lattices that you already had. Your question (when $n = 2$) is Exercise 1.10.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler I am so sorry to bother you again, does the modified question really hold for $m>1$? I tried it for a few days and I feels like it only works for $m=1$. Your any comments or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: I am tired of you repeatedly changing the question after it has been answered. I will not post anything further here.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the answer to the modified question for the case of $m=1$ is Yes, and I try to give my own proof as follows. But **I do not know if there is also an affirmative answer for $m>1$**.

We may assume that $ \bar{\rho}_{1} $ is non-semisimple and the matrix representation of $ \bar{\rho}_{1} $ has the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    A_1 & \ast & \cdots & \ast \\
    0 & A_2 & \cdots & \ast \\
    \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
    0 & 0 & \cdots & A_r
\end{pmatrix} $$
with only zeros below the boxed diagonal where each $ A_{i} $ is a block matrices corresponding to the irreducible components of $ \bar{\rho}_{1} $ for some integer $ r\geq 2 $. Suppose that $ A_{i} $ is a $ n_{i}\times n_{i} $ matrix. Then the semisimplification of $ \bar{\rho}_{1} $ turns this matrix into
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    A_1 & 0& \cdots & 0 \\
    0 & A_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
    \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
    0 & 0 & \cdots & A_r
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Moreover, the matrix representation of $ \rho $ must have the form
$$ \widetilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \widetilde{A_{1}} & \ast & \cdots & \ast \\
    pB_{21} & \widetilde{A_{2}} & \cdots & \ast \\
    \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
    pB_{r1} & pB_{r2} & \cdots &  \widetilde{A_{r}}
\end{pmatrix} $$
where each $ \widetilde{A_{i}} $ is a block matrix such that its mod $ p $ reduction is $ A_{i} $ for all $ i $ and $ B_{21},\cdots $ are some block matrices. Let $ L:=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[r]{p}) $ which is a totally ramified extension of $ \mathbb{Q}_p $ with degree $ r $. Then $ \pi_{L}=\sqrt[r]{p} $. We put
$$ Q:=\begin{pmatrix}
 (\sqrt[r]{p})^{r}I_{n_{1}} & 0 & \cdots  & 0 \\
0   &  (\sqrt[r]{p})^{r-1}I_{n_{2}} & \cdots &0  \\
\cdots  & \cdots & \cdots &\cdots  \\
0   & 0 & 0 &  (\sqrt[r]{p})I_{n_{r}}
\end{pmatrix} $$
where $ I_{n_{i}}  $ is the identity matrix of of size $ n_{i} $ for each $ i $. A simple calculation shows that
$$ Q\widetilde{A}Q^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \widetilde{A_{1}} & (\sqrt[r]{p})\ast & \cdots &    (\sqrt[r]{p})\ast \\
    (\sqrt[r]{p})\ast & \widetilde{A_{2}} & \cdots & (\sqrt[r]{p})\ast \\
    \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
    (\sqrt[r]{p})\ast &(\sqrt[r]{p})\ast & \cdots &  \widetilde{A_{r}}
\end{pmatrix}. $$
Then we define $ \rho' $ to be the composite of $ \rho $ and the conjugate by $ Q $. We are done.

We remark that the above argument is no longer valid for $m>2$.